# How do I select a specific set of <p> tags with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have the following HTML code that I am trying to parse
  [image: screenshot]

Can anyone please tell me how to select only the p tags in the box.
Or can anyone show me how to remove tags below the red line? Also, there are loads of unwanted p tags in the

div class="SPOSTARBUST-Related-Posts"

but

```
document.select("div.SPOSTARBUST-Related-Posts").remove();
```

doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following selector

```
div[id=content] > p
```

like this

```
    final String html = "<head><body/><div id=\"content\"><p>a</p><p>b</p><div><p>v</p></div></div></html>";
    final Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    final Elements ps = doc.select("div[id=content] > p");
    System.out.println(ps.size());
```

This will return all *direct* `p` children of `div[id="content"]`.

Comment: but I dont want all the "p" children

Comment: I would combine that with Alex' answer. ;-)

Comment: @Lai I just gave it as an example since on one hand you want to remove the `p` tags below the line and on the other there is a `p` tag above your selection inside the `div` tag. So what exactly are your criterias?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select just the `<p>` tags in the red box, as you can see the only criteria you can find is the `style="text-align: justify"`.

Using [JSoup selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) you can do it like this

```
Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p[style*=justify]");
```

Comment: I would combine that with ShyJ's answer.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a solution but if you notice, there is still an unwanted `<p style="text-align: justify;">....</p>` above the highligthed box area.